# Displaying node.js file inside a node.js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Trying to display this node.js file through my node.js server. However, all it does is display the code in proper format as if it were in notepad rather than actually displaying what it does in the console when executed. So in other words, I want my node.js file to execute and display on the browser, not just have the code display on the webpage.

```
var fs = require('fs'); 
var colour = require('colour');
var array = fs.readFileSync('songs/sister_golden_hair.txt').toString().split("\n"); 

var chordsArray =[];
var lyricsArray =[]; 
var count1 = 0;

for(var line in array) {
    count1++;   
    if (count1 >= 3) {          
        var count2 = 0; 
        lyricsArray[count1-3] = []; 
        chordsArray[count1-3] = [];
        while (array[line].indexOf("[") != -1) {
            lyricsArray[count1-3][count2] = array[line].substring(0, array[line].indexOf("["));
            array[line] = array[line].substring(array[line].indexOf("[")+1, array[line].length);
            chordsArray[count1-3][count2] = array[line].substring(0, array[line].indexOf("]"));
            array[line] = array[line].substring(array[line].indexOf("]")+1, array[line].length);
            count2++;
        }
        if (array[line].length > 0) {
            lyricsArray[count1-3][count2] = array[line];
            chordsArray[count1-3][count2] = "";
        }
    }
    else {
        console.log(array[line]);
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < chordsArray.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < chordsArray[i].length; j++) {
        if (j == 0) {
            for (var k = 0; k < lyricsArray[i][j].length; k++) {            
                process.stdout.write(" ");                                  
            }       
            process.stdout.write(chordsArray[i][j].green);                      
        }
        else {
            for (var k = 0; k < lyricsArray[i][j].length - chordsArray[i][j-1].length; k++) {
                process.stdout.write(" ");
            }       
            process.stdout.write(chordsArray[i][j].green);                      
        }
    }
    console.log();
    for (var j = 0; j < lyricsArray[i].length; j++) {
            process.stdout.write(lyricsArray[i][j].yellow);                     
    }
}
```

and here is the node.js server I am running where I try to say that if the client goes to "http://`127.0.0.1`/sister_golden_hair.html" then it should display the above node.js Here is the node.js server:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var counter = 1000;

function serveStaticFile(res, path, contentType, responseCode){
   if(!responseCode) responseCode = 200;
   fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(err, data){
     if(err){
       res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
       res.end('[' + counter++ + ']: ' + '500 INTERNAL FILE ERROR' + '\n');
     }
     else {
       res.writeHead(responseCode , {'Content-Type': contentType});
       res.end(data);

     }
   });
}

http.createServer(function (request,response){
     var path = request.url.replace(/\/?(?:\?.*)$/,'').toLowerCase();

   //write HTTP header

   var page = '';
   switch(path){
     case '/sister_golden_hair.html':
       serveStaticFile(response,
                       '/Problem4.js',
                       'application/javascript');
       break;
}
}).listen(3000, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server Running at http://127.0.0.1:3000  CNTL-C to quit');
```

Comment: Did you try using a content type of `text/javascript` instead of `application/javascript`?

Comment: @mscdex Yes I have and I also tried application/x-javascript and it still just displays it like so: http://i.gyazo.com/ace769d95601d2c49fc951b4a3bfe994.png

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use node.js code in the browser, you're going to need to use something like browserify.

Comment: I don't think we're allowed to use any packages or things like that. If you go to Part II of this page that is what we must do. http://people.scs.carleton.ca/~ldnel/2406fall2014/assignments/Assignment01/2406fall2014Assignment1.html

Comment: That link is password protected. Good luck re-implementing browserify though because that's really the only way you could run any kind of node.js-specific code in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using eval() - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval ? Check out the warning though.

Comment: How exactly would I use this to run the .js file "Problem4.js" inside the node.js server?

Comment: My hunch is that the browser is getting the contents back as a string which you could then pass to eval().